# Graph, Relation $xRy \Leftrightarrow$ There is a path between $x$ and $y$ - symmetry

Tags: graph-theory, relations, symmetry

I have the relation $xRy$ is equivalent to "There is a path between $x$ and $y$"

If I now want to check symmetry, $xRy$ is equivalent to $yRx$, I read that this is true. I thought this is only the case when you switch "path" to "road" since the definition of path is "A path is a road without repetition" and a road is a sequence $w = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k\}$.

So I assume that if two nodes are bound with a road you can go either way but with a path it's only into one direction (like in a directional graph). Can you explain the symmetry?

Comment: If $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_k$ is a path from $x_0$ to $x_k$, then $x_k,x_{k-1},\ldots,x_1,x_0$ is a path from $x_k$ to $x_0$. (By the way, the English for what you’re calling a *knot* (German *Knoten*?) is *vertex* or *node*.)

Comment: In what way is a path than different from a road? 
And yes, asummed bc of Knoten. Thanks for claryfing!

Comment: The difference is that a path is not allowed to repeat any node; a *trail* (German *Weg*) is allowed to repeat nodes. That is, the nodes of a path must be pairwise distinct; those of a trail need not be. (Sorry I didn’t catch the *road* at the same time that I noticed *knot*.) From [here](http://www.mathepedia.de/Wege,_Pfade,_Zyklen_und_Kreise.aspx): Einen Weg $W$ bezeichnet man als Pfad, falls alle Knoten in der Folge $W$ voneinander verschieden sind.

Comment: Hehe, good that you are into linguistics, thanks. 
Is there a chance that you mean "repeating edges"? If not, by "repeating nodes" you mean it like in the travelling salesman problem (I guess you are familiar with it), where he can only fly from node 1 to node 2 but not the other way around, so one-way flights. Like there's still a path, you just can't take it.

Comment: No, this problem is definitely about undirected graphs, so if there’s an edge from $v_1$ to $v_2$, it’s also an edge from $v_2$ to $v_1$. That’s why the relation $R$ is symmetric: if you were dealing with an arbitrary directed graph, $R$ would not necessarily be symmetric. What I mean is that if if $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$, and $v_5$ are the nodes of $K_5$, the complete graph on $5$ nodes, then $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a path from $v_1$ to $v_3$, and $v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5,v_2,v_3$ is a trail from $v_1$ to $v_3$ that is not a path, because it repeats the node $v_2$.

Comment: Ah I see! I thought that it's about the direction, that paths work like the edges in directed graphs and that trails are like in an undirected one and that it's about repeating the edges and not repeating the nodes. I now understand, thanks for the detailled explantion, I appreciate!

Comment: You’re welcome!